# Background database query doesnt return. Xamarin,forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.forms

I have a background process that I want to grab a token from a database, and send that to a server to check its validity. The query I have currently never returns anything. And when debugging, with a break on the query, and one on the line after, it never gets to the second break and doesnt throw an exception. The same query, and call to the site, works on the main thread, but not the background thread.

Ive been told I have a threading issue, and it seems a profiler would help me figure out exactly whats wrong, but to download the one for Xamarin, I would need to get the enterprise version of visual studio

```
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
private const string Url = "domain.com";
private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
public async Task BackgroudUpdate(CancellationToken tkn)
{
     await Task.Run(async () =>
     {
          Debug.Write("breakfastpls");
          var bar = await _connection.QueryAsync<Session>("SELECT * FROM 
              Session");
           Debug.Write("querySuccess");
          if (bar.Count > 0)
          {
                Debug.Write("yespls");
                var session = bar.First();
                var put = "{ \"token\" : \"" + session.token + "\" }";
                var response = await client.PutAsync(Url, new 
                    StringContent(put));
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Debug.Write("WAFFLE");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Write("Pancakes?");
                }
          }
          else
          {
                Debug.Write("barisgone");
          }
     });
}
```

The only Debug.Write I get in the output is "breakfastpls" and nothing else. in the output. I expected for the query to at least return something. But I dont know how to get it to do so.

Comment: I don't see the try/catch in your code, so how do you know it's not throwing an exception and not just silently suppressing it?

Comment: You don't need to wrap that code in `Task.Run()`. Not saying that is your problem, but the method is already async.

Comment: I have added a try catch to my code. There is still no exception.

Comment: Could be just be how your opening `_connection`, is it locked to one thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. All I had to do was initialize `_connection`. I now have the line `private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();`